# DDD - Hardcoded Ids in Domain Model

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have a Business Layer, where I have put all the Entities of the Domain Model.
Also there are Domain Services, where I put Domain Logic related to n Entities.
One entity is :

```cs
public class TypeOfIceCream
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class IceCreamOrder
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int IdTypeOfIceCream {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

My problem arises when I have to assign the typeOfIceCream to an IceCreamOrder.
I have a Domain Service:

```cs
public class IceCreamOrderDeliveryDomainService
{
     readonly IRepository<TypeOfIceCream> _repoTypeOfIceCream;
     //...

     public IceCreamOrder SetXXLIceCream(IceCreamOrder order)
     {
         //...other domain logic
         var typeXXL=_repoTypeOfIceCream.GetById(1); //How to avoid this!! I need to assign the Id of the state
         order.IdTypeOfIceCream= typeXXL.Id;
     }
}
```

As you see, my domain model, got infected by hard-coded Ids, but how can I avoid that? I want to assign specific types to IceCreams. 
I know the Ids, cause they are master-data that I am inserting while creating the Model and won't never change.

In the answers/comments someone is telling me to do this.
What do you think?

```cs
public class IceCreamOrderDeliveryDomainService
{
     readonly IRepository<TypeOfIceCream> _repoTypeOfIceCream;
     readonly IMasterData _masterData;

     public IceCreamOrderDeliveryDomainService(
         IRepository<TypeOfIceCream> repo,
         IMasterData masterData) {
         //....
      } 
     public IceCreamOrder SetXXLIceCream(IceCreamOrder order)
     {
         //...other domain logic
         var typeXXL=_repoTypeOfIceCream.GetById(_masterData.XXLIdTypeOfIceCream); //How to avoid this!! I need to assign the Id of the state
         order.IdTypeOfIceCream= typeXXL.Id;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why did you hard-code it?  Why don't you get that ID from somewhere else?  Like the requestor of the ice cream, maybe?

Comment: If you have a fairly fixed amount of types of ice cream, you could make TypeOfIceCream an Enumeration instead of a class.

Comment: `SetXXLIceCream()` violates open/closed principle.  You should get type of ice cream from a derived class method, or it should be injected.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I hardcoded them because I know they exists in the database, because they are in the seed data of my model.

Comment: @QuietSeditionist You mean , that I can inject the Ids as a MasterData interface (or something similar)?

Comment: @RikD , they could be enumerables, but as the Names of the states could change (imagine "XXL Ice Cream" in one year could be "Monster Ice Cream") So i need them to be editable, whithout touching code.

Comment: use a string id

Answer (score 0):

> As you see, my domain model, got infected by hard-coded Ids, but how can I avoid that? I want to assign specific types to IceCreams. I know the Ids, cause they are master-data that I am inserting while creating the Model and won't never change.

What I think you'll see in most cases is an extra level of indirection

```
var VANILLA = 1;
var typeXXL=_repoTypeOfIceCream.GetById(VANILLA);
```

Which is to say, we replace the domain agnostic primitive and replace it with a name that correctly expresses the domain semantics.

Then we try to move the assignment into a part of the code that makes sense.

```
var typeXXL=_repoTypeOfIceCream.GetById(MasterData.VANILLA);
```

You've probably seen this sort of approach in the handling of [HTTP status codes](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http/HttpStatus.java#L66).

```
int SC_SUCCESS = 200;
```

An example to consider is [UN/LOCODE](https://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/service/location.html), as used by Citerus in the [DDD Cargo Sample](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/location/SampleLocations.java).  The standard abbreviations are part of the language of the domain -- if shipping is your domain, you know about these codes, and perhaps even the revision protocols for them.

It would be perfectly reasonable to have a single module in your solution that knows how to represent locations as codes (strings), with your domain logic knowing the *name* for a code that it wants without necessarily knowing the string representation.

For literals - especially literals that are stable for the lifetime of the solution, it's largely a matter of taste whether your domain logic references the data directly `MasterData.VANILLA` or indirectly `MasterData.vanilla()`; whether to reference that name directly at the location that you need it, or instead pass it in as an argument (for instance, via a domain service).

Comment: Please, check the last part of the question again. What do you think? Is that looking nice for you?